# Determine the accumulation points of a complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I have to determine the accumulation points of the following complex sequence:

$a_{n}:=(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}})^{n}$

I believe that this sequence diverges, but I don't know how to prove it using limit considerations, since it is a complex sequence.

My first idea was to calculate the absolute value of $a_{n}$ and this is what I got:

$\left|a_n\right|=\left|\left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n\right|=\left|\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right|^n=1^n=1$

This means that all the elements of the sequence lie on the unit circle and thus the sequence is bounded, but how do I show that it diverges.

Comment: Hint: Multiplication of complex numbers on the unit circle corresponds to rotation.

Comment: Note that a bounded sequence of points in the complex plane must have accumulation points. [for a divergent but bounded sequence there will be more than one accumulation points]

Comment: Being divergent is not sufficient to decide whether a sequence has any accumulation points or not. Consider this simple example in natural numbers: $$a_n = \begin{cases}0 & \text{for } n \text{ even}\\n & \text{for }n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

The key ingredient to find the set of the accumulation points is the De Moivre's theorem stating that if $r(\cos\theta+ i \sin\theta)$ is a complex numbe, then
$$
\big(r\,(\cos\theta+ i \sin\theta)\big)^n= r^n\,(\cos n\theta+ i \sin n\theta)\qquad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
In the considered case
$$
a_n=\Big(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)^n=\Big(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\,\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\Big)^n=\cos\frac{n\pi}{4}+i\,\sin\frac{n\pi}{4}.
$$
Hence all possible accumulation points are
$$
\pm 1,\quad\pm i,\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\quad -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\quad -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If we do not have $|z_n| \to 0$, $z_n \to z$ iff $|z_n| \to |z|$ and $\arg(z_n) \to \arg(z)$. But $\arg(z_n) = \frac{n \pi}{4}$, which clearly does not converge.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't being careful; I do need that $z \neq 0$ (or equivalently, $|z_n|$ does not $\to 0$. Edited.